# Сортировка строк двумерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Вечер добрый! Есть двумерный массив, в котором содержится n-ое количество строк. Каждая строка представляет собой последовательность нулей и единиц, к примеру:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Надо отсортировать его построчно, но не каждую строку отдельно, а просто разместить строки по вертикали в нужном порядке. К примеру, для этого массива сортировка будет выглядеть так:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

То есть получается *поразрядная сортировка*. Как же мне её реализовать?

Comment: Как обычно - начинаете с последнего разряда, сортируете, переходя постепенно справа налево... Только сортировка должна быть устойчивой! Если, конечно, не хотите просто перевести строки в числа и отсортировать их :) Или просто сортировать строки какой-нибудь стандартной сортировкой типа `sort`...

Comment: @Harry, нет, сортировка с первого разряда, так как я заполнял строки с конца.

Comment: Ну что ж, наверное, вам виднее. Когда ничего не получится - пишите :)

Comment: @Harry, уже час бьюсь.Не могу :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не помещается у меня ответ в комментарий.
Чтоб сортировать поразрядно, нужны 1) устойчивая сортировка и 2) сортировка, начиная с последнего разряда к первому.

Ваш исходный массив:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

После сортировки по 7 разряду:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

После сортировки по 6 разряду:

```
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

После сортировки по 5 разряду:

```
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

После сортировки по 4 разряду:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

После сортировки по 3 разряду:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

После сортировки по 2 разряду:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

После сортировки по 1 разряду:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Похоже на то, что вам нужно?

Это - если вам преподаватель сказал помучиться. Если же нужно дело сделать - проще воспользоваться стандартной `std::sort()`.

Comment: Да, именно это мне и нужно.

Comment: Значит, начинать нужно с последнего (самого правого) разряда...

Comment: Помучиться надо ;)

Comment: Тогда главное - сохранить относительный порядок строк с одинаковыми числами в разряде сортировки. В каком хоть виде представлена матрица? Массив, вектор векторов, словом, какой вид она в программе имеет?

Comment: Двумерный массив (`int`).

Comment: Даю совет - выделите еще один массив и на каждом шаге копируйте в него сначала строки с 1 в нужном разряде, потом - с 0. Лишняя память - но зато *очень* простая реализация...

Comment: Желательно использовать минимальные затраты памяти и времени.

Comment: Ну я же не возражаю :) Принципиальный вопрос - *как* сортировать - мы решили. Теперь набрасывайте свою версию кода, будем ее с напильником доводить...

Comment: У меня получилось сделать сортировку на основе строк типа `string`, но данный метод кушает немало =)

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите QuickSort и примените его принципы к свой задаче. Для этого достаточно выполнять процедуру partition не относительно разделяющего элемента (pivot), а на каждом уровне рекурсии (L) обменивать строки с 1 или 0 в L-ом столбце.

Вот модифицированный псевдокод из вики для n строк и m столбцов.

```
 algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi, level) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi, level)

        if level < m - 1
            quicksort(A, lo, p – 1, level + 1)
            quicksort(A, p, hi, level + 1)

 algorithm partition(A, lo, hi, level) is
    i := lo
    j := hi    
    while i <= j do
        while A[i][level] = 1 do
          i := i + 1 
        while A[j][level] = 0 do
          j := j - 1 
        if i <= j then
            swap A[i] with A[j]
            i := i + 1
            j := j - 1
    return i
```

Comment: Желательно показать это *в коде*.

Comment: Покажите. Посмотрим и поправим, если что.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский ДАВАЙТЕ КАК ВЫ САМИ НАПИШИТЕ КОД

Comment: От минусов была бы польза, если бы минусаторы пояснили, что не так.

Comment: @MBo, думаю кто то не понел что вы написали или хотели сказать

Answer (score 0):

Трудно угадать, какие понятия доступны. Если можно использовать функторы, то поможет такой код:

```
class CmpBinary {
    const size_t n;
public:
    CmpBinary(const int column) : n(column){}
    bool operator()(bool* b1, bool* b2)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (b1[i] == b2[i]) continue;
            return (b1[i] > b2[i]) ? true : false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

В программе создаете массив указателей на первый элемент строк вашего двумерного массива.  Созданный массив сортируете по функтору (передавая ей количество столбцов) и получаете желаемый результат.